# Javascript Counter Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript

Working on making a 2 minute timer in JS.
I'm new so please bear with me.
I want to make the timer so that when you click the button (I already made the button in js), it decrements the time from 2 minutes. Here is what I have so far. The code doesn't go down second by second. Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you!

```
const startingMinutes = 2
let time = startingMinutes * 60

let timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

function countDown() {

  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
  let seconds = time % 60
  time--

  if (timerId <= -startingMinutes) {
    countdown.innerHTMl = 'Good Luck!'
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }

  if (timerId <= 0) {
    countdown.innerHTML = 'Time is up!'
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    countDown()
    countdown.innerHTML = minutes + ' minutes ' + ': ' + seconds + ' seconds '
  })
}

timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
```

Comment: You're doing compares against the timer ID, which shouldn't change--it's an ID, not the value of the timer. There are other issues as well, but start there. Please also consider consistent indentation--it makes reading code easier.

Comment: The `timerId` value returned by `setInterval()` has nothing at all to do with the interval time; it's a numeric id for the timer and it really does not  mean anything.

Comment: Also you set a click listener in a loop

Comment: You should be comparing `time`, not `timerId`.

Comment: Plus, you have two intervals running simultaneously, discarding the ID of the first.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I see that when I console log  the time it goes down. However when I view the button counter.innerHTML the number stays at 2 minutes.

I get this error in my console log.

app.js:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: minutes is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

I am trying to define the variable outside the function and no success. Is my whole code wrong? I thought I had a general idea of things now I am doubting my work. I am not looking for an answer moreso constructive help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This work successfully:

```js
const startingMinutes = 0.25
let time = startingMinutes * 60

let timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)

function countDown() {

  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
  let seconds = time % 60
  time--

  console.log(minutes, 'minutes:', seconds, 'seconds');
  
  if (time <= 0) {
    console.log('Time is up!');
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }
}
```

Then, just call **setInterval** with **countDown** function in your *click* handler